# Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated-v2

`Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?`

and,

```
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

I have tried most solutions provided and it doesn't work.
I add reaminated/plugin and restarted the server after clearing the cache.

Comment: Do you have babel.config.js file at root project folder ?

Comment: rebuild the app aslo if you are sure about adding the plugin in your `babel.config.js`

Comment: I have addressed the issue, I changed the babel.config.js file. Now it looks like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have addressed the issue, I changed the babel.config.js file. Now it looks like this.

```
api.cache(true);
return {
  presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ['..............*other plug ins*'],
    },
  },
};
};
```

and then `expo r -c` if you are using expo.

Comment: If you have resolved your own problem, please mark your answer as the accepted answer.